# app icon is missing for iTunes app accelerator in Xcode Organizer (appcelerator)

Tags: appcelerator, itunes-store, appcelerator-titanium

When I build my titanium app in appcelerator, the app icon is missing from the organiser when I build it for app store submission

[image]

How can I resolve this thanks

Edit:

In itunes connect, this is how it appears after I select the build:

[image]

Icon is missing.

Comment: Well, can you submit it to the app store?

Comment: Yes, but there is no app icon in itunes connect either

Comment: Did you upload the icon manually to iTunes Connect under "General App Information?"

Comment: Then this could be just temporary. I would just submit the app and see. If an app is missing its icon, I don't think Apple will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we need to have the iTunesArtwork(512X512) and iTunesArtwork@2x(1024X1024) in the folder Resource->iphone-> here we need to have that 2 files.

Comment: It's only needed for adhoc build. Don't include it in app store distribution. [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-AddingyouriTunesArtworktoyourproject)

Comment: @shawn True, but I do see an icon in Xcode and iTunes Connect - even though I don't have those iTunesArtwork files. So it appears to be a different problem. bobo2000 could you upload a zip with your icons somewhere?

Comment: That's what I mean. You don't need these files unless for a adhoc build.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem recently. I don't know the real reason behind that, but I find that if I change the extension of the image file directly from jpg to png, the AppIcon will not show in the organizer. However, if I open the image with the preview application, export png version of the image and add it to Xcode, the AppIcon will show in the organizer.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the `iTunesArtwork` and `iTunesArtwork@2x` images in the root of your Titanium project? They are simply `png` images without the extension. They go in the same folder as the `tiapp.xml`.

Comment: It's only needed for adhoc build. Don't include it in app store distribution. [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-AddingyouriTunesArtworktoyourproject)

Answer (score -1):

Check alpha channel for all app icons. If alpha channel is exist then just remove alpha channel and then try it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For iOS Only
If you are using Ti SDK >= 5.0.0 GA  you must make  an Icon called `DefaultIcon.png` and Ti will make all icons you want automatically !.

`You are recommended to add a 1024 x 1024 PNG image, named DefaultIcon.png placed in the project's root folder, which is used to generate all or only omitted icons for the project. New Titanium projects will have the DefaultIcon.png file.`

Reference https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/release-notes/?version=5.0.0.GA

For iOS and Android http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/ it`s awesome tool from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4626813/fokke-zandbergen

Comment: Is it DefaultIcon.png or DefaultIcon-ios.png?  (with ios) I am using v 5.0.0

Comment: Sorry i`ts DefaultIcon.png according to the docs http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-iOSgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions

Comment: Yep, have that, and it does automatically make the icons for me, but when I upload it to itunes via xcode, the app icon is missing (as in the screenshot)

Comment: Did you upload the app on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/  ?? , i faced this issue before but when upload the app on `itunesconnect` it works without anything , Can you check that ?

Comment: I created the app for distribution through appcelerator, after it creates the package I then go into xcode, and then upload it. On both Xcode and itunes connect even if the app is there, the app icon is not next to the build (as above).

Comment: I`m sure ِxcode disallowed uploading app with missed a required icons ! , must all app icons attached in the app !

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from itunesconnect ?

Comment: Just to clarify, DefaultIcon.png is not required. You can either have icons of different sizes like before, or use one DefaultIcon.png.