# appcelerator sdk 5x missing appicon in xcode organizer

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I build my app in appcelerator studio using SKD 5.x, the appicon is missing from the Xcode organizer when I build it for app store submission. I did find this question [app icon is missing for iTunes app accelerator in Xcode Organizer (appcelerator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260214/app-icon-is-missing-for-itunes-app-accelerator-in-xcode-organizer-appcelerator) but none of the answers worked and I am not able to add addition comment to that question. It appears that this happens because Appcelerator SDK 5.x no longer supports a number of previously used pixel resolutions for appicon. Can anybody confirm that this is an issue with the newer SDK and if there is a fix?

[v5 Xcode missing icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKbm0.png)
[v4 Xcode has icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfAyU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that we no longer include the `iTunesArtwork` and `iTunesArtwork@2x` icons in production builds. This icon is really only used for Ad-Hoc builds, but it looks like its also used by xCode.

You can just ignore it.